# Python Pandas to_datetime row by row

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert a DF column row by row to_datetime, so when there is a string that is not capable of beeing turned into datetime format, skip that row?

This line of code turns the whole column into datetime format, but some of the rows are set as "friday" and not dates, so I want to skip these rows and format the rest.

```
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Any help?

Comment: can you please clarify how that row which is converted to friday instead of the full date is different? It will help.

Comment: The 'friday' value was already there. It wasnt converted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `errors='coerce'` for this

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you clarify how 'coerce' is different from errors='ignore' from the answer bellow?

Comment: From the documentation:

`errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}`, default ‘raise’
If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.

If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.

If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

Comment: So it depends on what you want to see if it's Friday, if you want to see NaT then use `coerce`, if you want to see Friday then use `ignore`.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the error you are receiving.

```
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore')
```